# Android preferences dependency

Tags: android

I have four checkboxes. Checkbox 2 & 4 should be enabled if the checkbox above them are enabled. So I set their dependency like this:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_private_chat" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="private_chat_notification"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_notification_summary"
        android:title="@string/preferences_notification_notification_title" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="private_chat_notification"
        android:key="private_chat_vibrate"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_notification_summary"
        android:title="@string/preferences_notification_vibrate_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_room_chat" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="room_chat_notification"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_notification_summary"
        android:title="@string/preferences_notification_notification_title" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:dependency="room_chat_notification"
        android:key="room_chat_vibrate"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_notification_summary"
        android:title="@string/preferences_notification_vibrate_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_account" >
    <Preference
        android:key="account_delete"
        android:title="@string/preferences_account_delete" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

When disabling the first checkbox ALL of the other checkboxes are changing their colour:[image]

Even though, the last two checkboxes are still clickable (as they should) and the second is correctly disabled.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an android bug?

Edit: All checkboxes checked
[image]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the `private_chat_notification` checkbox checked? So far your code looks good to me, so I'm not sure myself, almost does look like a bug. Android version and SDK you are building against?

Comment: I am testing it on my device with Android 4.1.2. minSdkVersion is 11 and targetSdkVersion 21. I've attached a screenshot with all checkboxes checked.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to test it out myself, but so far that looks like a bug to me. Do you have any way of testing on another device or different Android version? Emulator perhaps? That may narrow it down. I've combed your code and it looks right to me.